# Flutter dose not connect to socket server

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I've set up my node socket io server on a VPS and now trying to connect the flutter app to the server, the problem here is that when I run the app as web (running on chrome desktop), it works perfect and communicates with the server. but when I run it as android app, no data gets transferred.
I'm using  socket_io_client: ^0.9.11 package in my flutter app.
Have no idea what is wrong with it!

Comment: perhaps share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have declared the correct permissions for the android app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

More info here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking